# How can I swap 1 letter and give all possible letter in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, swap

How can I swap only "one" letter and give all possible output in python3 and append into the list

for example: the word "study"
we will have all possible output like

```
swap the s:
tsudy, tusdy, tudsy, tudys, 
#swap the t:
tsudy, sutdy, sudty, sudyt
#also with u,d,y:
...
```

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Comment: split word in list of chars, remove char - ie. `s` - and use for-loop to put this char in different places in list using `list.insert(position, 's')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert word into list of chars,

```
chars = list(word)
```

remove selected char from list using its position

```
chars.pop(index)
```

and later add this char in different places in this list

```
new_chars = chars[:pos] + [char] + chars[pos:]
```

---

Code:

```
word = 'study'

for index, char in enumerate(word):
    print('char:', char)
    # create list without selected char
    chars = list(word)
    chars.pop(index)

    # put selected char in different places
    for pos in range(len(chars)+1):
        # create new list 
        new_chars = chars[:pos] + [char] + chars[pos:]
        new_word = ''.join(new_chars)

        # skip original word
        if new_word != word:
            print(pos, '>', new_word)
```

Result:

```
char: s
1 > tsudy
2 > tusdy
3 > tudsy
4 > tudys
char: t
0 > tsudy
2 > sutdy
3 > sudty
4 > sudyt
char: u
0 > ustdy
1 > sutdy
3 > stduy
4 > stdyu
char: d
0 > dstuy
1 > sdtuy
2 > stduy
4 > stuyd
char: y
0 > ystud
1 > sytud
2 > styud
3 > stuyd
```

---

**BTW:** I wouldn't call it `"swapping"` but `"moving"` char. In "swapping" I would rather replace two chars - ie. swapping `a` with `c` in `abcd` gives `cbad`, not `bcad` (like in "moving")